# Nuxt problema al regresar a una pagina

Tags: nuxt

Hola comunidad espero se encuentren bien, tengo un problema con nuxt resulta ser que tengo 2 layouts uno que es el por defecto y otro que incluye un v-navigation-drawer.

básicamente estoy usando vuetify para los estilos pero el layout default solo esta vacío y ahí cargo la pagina índex esta pagina nada mas es un login y paso a la siguiente pagina con

`<v-btn type="submit" color="green" block class="mt-2" to="/menu">Iniciar sesion</v-btn>`

la ruta /menu usa como layout otro que no es la por defecto y que para regresar al login hago lo siguiente

```
<v-btn text href="/">Cerrar sesion</v-btn>
```

para volver al login todo normal, hasta que voy al /menú y luego me regreso al login osea la ruta raiz, si repetido esto varia veces tarda muchisimo en cambiar de pagina, mas que nada de la ruta raiz a la de /menu, porque sucede esto?

Dejo la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]